# TexShop + MacVim ?

Tags: vim, texshop

Is there a blend of TexShop and Vim?

It is supposed to combine the advantages of SyncTeX and other features of TeXShop and the power of a Vim editor.

Comment: You may try Skim as a previewer, it understands synctex and works well with Aquamacs and other editors. In its preferences panel it claims support also for MacVim.

Comment: yeah this works well! can it do forward searches (from TeX to pdf) too?

Comment: Yes, the vim-latex suite [vim-latex.sourceforge.net] supports this (the default key mapping for forward search is `mapleader-l-s`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try [Skim](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net/) as a previewer, it understands SyncTeX and works well with [Aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org) and other editors. In its "Preferences" panel it claims support also for [MacVim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/).

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: @Dominique The OP was trying to use TeXShop as a PDF viewer and Vim as the editor.

Comment: I know, but I don't see how using Skim answers the question. I use TeXShop as an external PDF viewer and edit my documents in another editor.

Comment: @Dominique The OP was satisfied with the answer; if you know a better method with TeXShop, please add an answer. I believe that Skim is very good as a previewer and does better than TeXShop in this respect.