# Is it possible to use an external editor with TeXShop, while keeping its sync features?

Tags: editors, texshop, forward-inverse-search

I'm not completely satisfied with TeXShop's internal editor (especially about [line breaking](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16510/indentation-and-line-wraps-in-texshop)), but I would like to keep using TeXShop for its neat visualization engine and sync features (inverse and forward search). Is it possible to keep those functionalities, or at least a decent inverse search, while using an external editor with TeXShop? If so, do you have any suggestions about a suitable editor for Mac?

Comment: Why not use some other editor which has inverse and forward search? (Emacs works, for instance.)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this [page about using TeXShop with an external editor](http://ftp2.pl.freebsd.org/pub/TeX/TeXShop/texshop%202.26/TeXShop.app/Contents/Resources/Dutch.lproj/TeXShopHelp/pgs/advanced_externaleditor.htm).  You can configure TeXShop to open files in another editor, and if that editor can run unix commands, TeXShop provides executables for its interactive compiling.

Comment: But probably not sync. Not sure.

Comment: Thanks! I had already read that, but it gave me no hint about syncing. So far I only tried with vim, but cmd-clicking the PDF in TeXShop for inverse search had no effect. I wonder if I need to change some setting in TeXShop, use a more powerful editor (vim was just a try), or if I'm simply asking too much...

Comment: PDF syncing is still magic to me, but AFAIK it's an operating system library. So I believe that for an editor to support this it has to be really mac-aware.  Is there a verision of vim that's well integrated as a mac app?

Comment: I don't think so. And I'm not a big vim fan; it's just the only other editor that I have already installed and that came to my mind. I would be happy to use another editor, if that worked. Thanks again...

Comment: just found the [TeXShop + MacVim ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17959/texshop-macvim) question among the Related ones, going to research a bit.

Comment: That “page about using TeXShop with an external editor” <http://ftp2.pl.freebsd.org/pub/TeX/TeXShop/texshop%202.26/TeXShop.app/Contents/Resources/Dutch.lproj/TeXShopHelp/pgs/advanced_externaleditor.htm> seems to have been moved (or disappeared).  Does anyone know more?

Answer (score 1):

As of TeXShop 4.24, Prof. Richard Koch has included a preliminar synchronisation from the viewer to the editor. It's currently implemented (as a general solution) by using an external script. From TeXShop, choose the menu Help->Changes to see how it can be made to work with other editors.

Answer (score 0):

many many editors support this. Emacs and auctex does with the `synctex` package. So does texniccenter on windows.

It's not just for mac... but check out http://mactex-wiki.tug.org/wiki/index.php/SyncTeX

Comment: But can the OP use, for instance, Emacs and TeXShop in sync?